# Get Xspec test results with inline CSS within Ant

Tags: xspec

Xspec delivers HTML reports with test results. I'm looking for a way to avoid having an absolute path to a CSS file in the Xspec report.

I saw that [there is a command-line option `-i` to place the CSS inline](https://github.com/xspec/xspec/pull/111) in the HTML page. The script version uses inline=true as the default.

However, the default in the stylesheet to format the HTML report is `false`. I'm calling Xspec from Ant, and I don't seem to find a way to add this option in the Ant call. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm answering this even if you found out the answer by posting on GitHub, hopefully it will be useful for other people.

As answered on [GitHub](https://github.com/xspec/xspec/pull/391), the functionality to have inline CSS when running XSpec with Ant is currently in two pull requests which should be merged soon into the master branch of XSpec. In the meantime you can use the [branch in this pull request](https://github.com/xspec/xspec/pull/266) to have this functionality. Any feedback is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Thanks, I should have added the link here indeed! There are a lot of changes in the PR. It seems to work fine for me, but I haven't done a lot of testing yet.